# Printing Pyramid Puzzle

Tags: algorithm

Derive an algorithm for **printing a pyramid with all possible combination** such that lightest and smallest person lie on top of pyramid and heaviest and biggest person as a base

For Example :

Person A 80kg 140 cms

Person B 90kg 150 cms

Person C 100kg 160 cms

Person D 100kg 170 cms

Person E 150kg 180 cms

Person F 160kg 185 cms

```
  A
 B C
D E F
```

Note: 
Person with height and weight larger than other person cannot lie on top of that person
Its not mandotory for every person to be part of pyramid structure

Comment: Is the pyramid required to be "full"? i.e. in this case a 1 person, 3 person or a 6 person pyramid?   Also, Can B be heavier or taller than F in your figure?

Comment: Its not necessary for pyramid to be full. it can be 3 person 6 person pyramid. (1 person pyramid is not possible though).

Comment: @dfens: No, I also fell for it, a node can have 2 parents in this pyramid [look at `E` in the OP's example], unlike a heap.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rough idea.

Construct a graph in a way that an directed edge goes from node X to Y if  `X > Y` (both components) and there's no such `Z` that `X > Z > Y`, for your example

```
       / C \
F -> E       B -> A
       \ D /
```

Then construct all trees of hight 1, and recursively construct the rest like so:

Mark all used nodes in the tree (initially, just one node)
For putting a person `X` under another 2 persons `Y Z` you can only use persons that in the graph are **under** `Y Z`

use all permutations and recursively repeat until you can construct no more